# Laravel 5.1 Custom table names and field names

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using a already setup database to upgrade an old application to Laravel 5.1 and using out-of-the box authentication system (built-in). The registration/login works only when I use email and password as field name, otherwise it let the user register but not let them login. My question is can we use own filed names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to change the `migrations` & `User` Model's `$fillable` property... `AuthController` and `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers` `postLogin` and `loginUsername` methods

Comment: Thanks shafi, not only in migrations, user model's fillable but also in AuthController too. but still not working.

Comment: plz let me know some changes that you are trying. I'll try to do the same

Comment: I see you need to change `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers` also... Now I suggest to do something else.. and not try to mess up the code... However, still update your question and explain the changes you are trying to do..

Comment: In the db, I have fields co_Password, co_Name, co_Email. that I want to use in laravel auth. I can't change the field names as these are in use by other app too. well, if we update the traits like AuthenticatesUsers, on next artisan update, these will be overwritten?

Comment: Then I believe @thomas-kim has suggested a nice solution.
Changes to `AuthController` and `User` Model are acceptable..

Comment: thank you for your help, I am working and following @pespantelis provided solution. Let´s see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `username` property to the AuthController.

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    protected $username = 'field_name';

    ...
}
```

Check the `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers@loginUsername` method.

#### Edit

If you want to change the `password` field name (or to use another field in laravel auth), you should override the `postLogin` method, because it is hardcoded.

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'co_Email' => 'required', 'co_Password' => 'required'
    ]);

    $throttles = $this->isUsingThrottlesLoginsTrait();

    if ($throttles && $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    $credentials = $request->only('co_Email', 'co_Password');

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
        return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);
    }

    if ($throttles) {
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
    }

    return redirect($this->loginPath())
        ->withInput($request->only('co_Email', 'remember'))
        ->withErrors([
            'co_Email' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
        ]);
}
```

Comment: thanks, I just updated the Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers file change the postLogin function with the code, the only different with your code is, we do not need the co_Name as required field. plus I also updated the getCredentials function in same file. <code> protected function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'co_Password');
    } </code> Now when login, it show an error message <b>These credentials do not match our records. </b>

Comment: Oh sorry, your [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34341780/laravel-5-1-custom-table-names-and-field-names/34342079#comment56425706_34341828) confused me. Without the `co_Name` field, that it works like a charm.

Comment: co_Name field is in Reg. form .that is working properly. Now, I update the code in AuthenticatesUsers, in User model, Login view, and AuthController.php file that is in  app/Http/Controllers/Auth but still the same error message.

Comment: issue is with the login auth

Answer (score 0):

Laravel makes this pretty simple. Like @pespantelis said, you can override the email field. In your form:

```
<input type="email" name="co_Email">
```

Then, in your `AuthController`:

```
protected $username = 'co_Email';
```

In order for Laravel to look at the correct column for the password while still using the default authentication system, it's a tad different but still just as easy. Just follow these steps:

1. Don't alter the name of your password field so just name it "password" as you would do normally:

   ```
   <input type="password" name="password">
   ```
2. But add this method to your User model:

   ```
   public function getAuthPassword()
   {
       return $this->co_Password;
   }
   ```

Laravel will then compare the "password" field with the "co_Password" column.